What is the geometric meaning of the square of the second fundamental form being A^2= 1/2|A|^2 g|_S?
What is the geometric meaning of the square of the second fundamental form being A^2= 1/2|A|^2 g|_S? Here, A is the second fundamental form of a surface S on a three-dimensional Riemannian manifold of metric g.

You don’t mean traceless. You mean the trace-free part is zero.

Trace-free means the same thing as traceless. For $A^2$ it means that $$\operatorname{trace}(A^2)= 0.$$ This is not the same as saying $$A^2 = \frac{1}{2}|A|^2\left.g\right|_S. $$
